# Multiple Rasters in Zonal Statistics in a For-loop?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, arcpy

I am working on a project for my beginners' Python class and have gotten a little stuck. I have three .tif files that I want to do Zonal Statistics for, but I am getting an error. Here is my script:

```
import arcpy
import os
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
env.workspace = r'C:\Users\alvaremi\Documents\Final Project_Python'
path = r'C:\Users\alvaremi\Documents\Final Project_Pythonn'
env.overwriteOutput = 1
arcpy.CheckOutExtension('Spatial')

in_zone_data = 'counties_in_cog.shp'
zone_field = 'NAME'

impervious = os.listdir(env.workspace + '\ImpvClipped')
print impervious

for year in impervious:
  if year.endswith(".tif"):
    outZonalStatistics = ZonalStatistics(in_zone_data, zone_field, year, "MEAN", "NODATA")
    outZonalStatistics.save(year[:8] + 'zonalstats')

print 'Done'
```

When I run it, I get this error: 
    ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
    ERROR 000865: Input value raster: 2001impvclipped.tif does not exist.
    Failed to execute (ZonalStatistics).

I am also unsure of how to save the new files so that they keep the date on them. The files I want to run the Zonal Stats on are "2001impclipped", "2006impclipped", and "2011impclipped".

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the full directory path to the filename in order for Python to find it.

```
fileName = env.workspace + '\ImpvClipped\' + year
ZonalStatistics(in_zone_data, zone_field, fileName, "MEAN", "NODATA")
```